# How to create View partially invisible

Tags: android, view

What I'd like to achieve is effect like the one in the picture:
[image]

So basically there's a `TextView` which slowly disappears. I don't want whole `View` to be made for example 50% transparent, but rather for example left part of it to be 0% transparent, and it smoothly goes into 100% transparency at the right side.

I know that some components (e.g. `ListView`) uses this, but is it possible to do it manually in quite easy way?

Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: Create a view with a left to right gradient transparency from 0 to 100% alpha.  Move that view right to left over your TextView with a timer or use an Animation.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Write it as answer, please. So I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create a shape with an alpha gradient.  Place the XML into your drawable directory.  Let's call it gradient_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Now create a view in your layout to the right of your TextView.  You'll need to set width and height appropriately and position in your view as required (RelativeLayout with layout_toTheRightOf would work well).

```
<View android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_view"/>
```

In the right place in your code, animate it.  Change the -200 to whatever you need (or even better, find the left X of your gradient view and subtract the left edge of your TextView to find the amount to move).

```
TranslationAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, -200, 0, 0);
anim.setDuration(1000);
myTextView.startAnimation(anim);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

There's a bit more work to do but this is most of what you need.

Good luck