# How to make a linearLayout partially transparent in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` containing 2 `LinearLayouts` one of them is partially covering the other. I want to make the part of the `LinearLayout` on top transparent so I can also see the 2nd `LinearLayout` **knowing that i have 2 images as background for the 2 `LinearLayouts`**.

Comment: so you want the covered part of layout 1 which is partially covering layout 2, transparent?

Comment: @user2137817 can u post ur layout code? I am in need of the same thing what u posted

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When we set the color it is like **ARGB(Alpha Red Green Blue)**. You need to ***change the alpha in the color code to increase or decrease the amount of Transparency*** :

**You can range it from 00 to FF (Hexa Decimal)**

**For maximum transparency =>** #00555555 (Here **00** stands for the alpha)

**For minimum or no transparency =>** #FF555555 (Here **FF** stands for the alpha)

So, *for setting the **transparency of an ImageView** you can code like this:*

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
image.setAlpha(0.3);
```

Also, you can *set the alpha for your **LinearLayout** like this* :

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
ll.setAlpha(0.4);
```

Comment: the problem is, if i change the alpha for a linealayout, the children will be transparent as well and i don't want that

Comment: Then make your LinearLayout transparent. Then add a ImageView and control the transparency of that ImageView.

Comment: my problem is the children, i have text views inside the linealayout and if i modify the alpha value, the textviews become transparent aswell

Comment: Read my previous comment properly. You need to add an ImageView to take for containing the image and above it place the TextViews.

Comment: it's not really what i want but close enough, thanks

Comment: However this causes a crash on Api 6 and Api 4.4 have you faced this crash ?

Answer (score 30):

Use this in your Layout

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

0.0 is totally transparent, 1.0 is fully opaque.

Comment: Why did i have to look for an answer like this for half an hour..? So goddamn simple yet affective, nice!

Comment: Well that didn´t last long.. it failed on build-time with:

"String types not allowed (at 'alpha' with value '0.5f')."

Comment: Just use it like `android:alpha="0.5"`

Answer (score 14):

Make your `LinearLayout` Background Transparent :

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and for making your Layout Partially Transparent maybe this Link Helps you : [How to create View partially invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380320/how-to-create-view-partially-invisible)

**Edit:** if you have an Image as Background of your layout so i think you can set alpha for your LinearLayout and control it from code without changing your background, to Transparent your Layout with Background Image :

```
android:alpha=""

alpha property of the view, as a value between 0 (completely 
transparent) and 1 (completely opaque)
```

Answer (score 5):

set Top Linear Layout's background as

background="#CCFFFFFF" in your layout.xml file

change alpha mode for more transparency here "CC".

("00" as full transparent)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4990254/665561

Answer (score 3):

> It is so late but it will be helpful for others....
>
> create xml file like this...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#234234"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickNext"
        android:text="Next >" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha=".05"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> now go to your manifest... and add this line...

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" 
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

enjoyyyy...

Answer (score 3):

set the background color like this:

```
android:background="#00ffffff"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the theme to the activity which needs to be transparent in your Manifest file.

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
   </activity>
```